# How can I migrate existing model (includes inserted rows) from nullable column to not nullable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, database-migration

I created a model with column definition

```
create_table :admin_authentication_tokens do |t|
    t.integer :authentication_ttl
end
```

And now I want to make the `authentication_ttl` not nullable. I tried with this migration

```
change_column :admin_authentication_tokens, :authentication_ttl, :integer, null: false, default: 0
```

But got an error
`PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  column "authentication_ttl" contains null values`

I understand what the error means but I don't want to migrate the model by manually. So please give me a way to migrate the model with migration file.

Comment: I found my answer: `MyModel.where(authentication_ttl: nil).update_all(authentication_ttl: 0)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot add a `NOT NULL` constraint to a column that contains null values.

One way or another, you need to get rid of these values before performing such a migration.

For example, as you suggested above, perhaps these should all be set to `0`:

```
MyModel.where(authentication_ttl: nil).update_all(authentication_ttl: 0)
```

...Or maybe there's some other value that (some of) these columns could be set to?

Or maybe these rows don't actually make sense, and should be deleted?

```
MyModel.where(authentication_ttl: nil).delete_all
```

(Or perhaps you should `destroy_all`, to trigger rails callbacks?)

In short, the answer really depends on your specific circumstances. But one way or another, you need to get rid of the `null`s first.

Note that if you have a production environment as well as a local one, then this needs to be taken into consideration before deployment. Again, one way or another (e.g. perhaps via a rake task), you'd need to "fix" the production data before deploying such a migration.